# How to setting contact form 7 plugin to get messages from guest users without email

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I use plugin [Contact Form 7](https://contactform7.com/) in my wordpress project and I have custom form with fields:

- name
- phone
- message

When I try send message as guest user get error with message:

```
{
    additional_errors: []
    code: "wp_die"
    data: {status: 500}
    message: "You are not authorized to perform this action."
}
```

How solve this problem?

Comment: Post your contactform7 code?  Also, perhaps try [disabling users enumeration](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/contact-form-7-doesnt-work-with-the-feature-users-enumeration/) if it's enabled.

Comment: did you tried  also with all other plugins disabled ?

Answer (score 4):

I resolve this issue by doing the following in "All In One WP Security & Firewall".

1. Go to Miscellaneous
2. Go to WP REST API
3. List item
4. Uncheck Disallow Unauthorized REST Requests:
5. List item

Submit

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem.